# Firebase Cloud Firestore - How to query two sub-collections simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to query two sub-collections of a `DocumentReference`.

I tried doing the following:

```
var promise1 = admin.firestore().collection(`players/${id}/collection1`).get();
var promise2 = admin.firestore().collection(`players/${id}/collection2`).get();

return Promise.all(promise1, promise2)
```

The problem though, is that by doing the following I get the following error:

> TypeError: (var)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
>       at Function.all (native)
>       at exports.onSubmission.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/user_code/index.js:671:20)

So, I tried nesting them as below and it worked fine.

```
 return admin.firestore().collection(`players/${id}/collection1`).get().then(foundersSnapshot => {
    return admin.firestore().collection(`players/${id}/collection2`).get().then(metricsSnapshot => {
```

However, when deploying I get the warning saying

> Avoid nesting promises

So, what are the best practices in this case? I would prefer doing through `Promise.all` but it doesn't work. Also, it would output two collections as results in the `then(results => {` So, in this case, could I safely regard `results[0]` as "collection1" and `results[1] as "collection2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all()` requires a single array parameter.  Note the square brackets around `promise1` and `promise2` that make an inline array out of them:

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
```